# Create and apply "patch" between two different SVN Server?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Basically, There are ***two*** different Svn server and each one of them used by different groups are working on the ***same*** project. I am trying to find out a way to merge changes using svn's functionality.

In order to make **Test**: I have created two repository (`file:///D:/FirstRepo` and `file:///D:/SecondRepo`) in my local and added same file(`test.txt`) like a project. After changed the file in first repository, I created a patch and apply the patch to other repository. It does not work properly. If these two files are not synchronized (*files' contents are completely same*), the patch that created comes empty.

So, what way should be selected to achieve this goal? Is my way good approach and Is it developable?

Thanks in advance.

**Note**:

- TortoiseSVN is used for SVN client.
- Both svn server is closed to connect from outside.

Comment: How do those collaborators work on the same project but in different repositories? Do you use repository replication?

Comment: Yes, actually one of them (repositories) is going to be production version at the end. Now, merging is making with copy paste method (guess you mean that with repository replication).

Comment: Hmm.. This is a new one for me. Interesting. I can understand the intent behind it, but I have a question. So, `SecondRepo` is meant to be a production repository, but if you're not doing any development on it and simply copying changes from the first repo, what would be the difference aside from simply using `tags` or `branches` for your production group? Is there any specific conditions that require these repos to be separate? I feel like simply tagging checkpoints in your dev cycle will accomplish this goal.

Comment: Firstly Thank you @Chris. second or first repo will be production but now both repository is open to development.  The main intent behind this is security (cyber) and company policy . Subgroups do not communicate each other during this developing process. I will make research about that " tagging checkpoints in your dev cycle".

Answer (score 1):

-- In response to your last comment.

Oh, well if that's the case, then yeah I definitely have a solution for you. I thought you had something different in mind.

Even if your teams don't communicate, you can still host the code under the same repository and even if you host the two teams under the same repository, you can give the groups access/block access down to specific directories and they will never see the others.

Subversion supports [Path Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) where you basically take a set of groups, and you give them permissions to the directories as they are required.

So let's say you have two groups: `team-one` and `team-two`, and these two teams, as you say have access to only these specific directories. If you setup authz file authorization, you can explicitly set permissions on all of your directories in your repository, therefore, you will only need *one* repository.

```
[groups]
admins = krezus
team-one = chris, john
team-two = jim, ted

[RepoName:/MyProject]
@admins = rw

[RepoName:/MyProject/trunk]
@team-one = rw

[RepoName:/MyProject/branches]
@team-two = rw

[RepoName:/MyProject/tags]
@team-one = rw
@team-two = r
```

In this quick example, you're the admin. Therefore, you have access to everything under `RepoName/MyProject`. `team-one` being the main development team, they have `read-write` access to the `trunk` and `tags`. `team-two` won't have access to any of these files under trunk.

However, during your dev cycle, you periodically make "releases" of your code for `team-two` to use. You can then make a **tag** of your `trunk` at a certain revision and copy it to the `tags` directory. `team-two` can *read* the tag and they can pull changes into any of their code under `branches`, which no one has access to except them.

The would cover pretty much everything you're trying to accomplish:

- Keeping directories locked down for certain users
- Merging changes from one project to the next

Comment: thank you @Chris. it is useful answer but I think it is not what I need. It seems like my comment's answer more than question. Even so, I will try your solution.